# Spring MVC + Hibernate executing a not coded update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm using Spring MVC with Hibernate but I've reached a weird situation, when my Service annotated with @Transational finishes it's execution it seems that hibernate is executing an extra update in my entity, an update that is not coded anywhere. Could someone help me?
My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Resource(name="userService")
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView createUser(User user) throws GenericException {

        this.userService.doTestOnUpdateUser();

        return new ModelAndView("createUser");
    }
```

My Service:
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

```
@Resource(name = "userDao")
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = CauseTrasactionRollback.class)
public void doTestOnUpdateUser() {
    try {
        User user = this.userDao.findById(40l);
        user.setFirstName("Rogerio1234");
        user.setLastName("R123");
        user.setEmail("rro@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("novo password");

        this.userDao.save(user);
        System.out.println("why ?");

    } catch (DaoException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

My DAO:

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl extends CrudDaoImpl<User> implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    public UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) throws DaoException {
        try {

            String sql = "";
            User userBefore = null;

            if (user.getId() == null) {
                user.setCreated(new Date());
                sql = "insert into users (first_name, last_name, email, password, created, last_updated, email_confirmed_at)"
                        + "values (:firstName, :lastName, :email, md5(:password), :created, :lastUpdated, :emailConfirmedAt)";
            } else {
                userBefore = this.findById(user.getId());
                user.setLastUpdated(new Date());
                if (userBefore.getPassword() != user.getPassword()) {
                    sql = "update users set first_name=:firstName, last_name=:lastName, email=:email, "
                            + " password=md5(:password), created=:created, last_updated=:lastUpdated, "
                            + " email_confirmed_at=:emailConfirmedAt where id=:id";
                } else {
                    sql = "update users set first_name=:firstName, last_name=:lastName, email=:email, "
                            + "created=:created, last_updated=:lastUpdated, email_confirmed_at=:emailConfirmedAt where id=:id";
                }
            }

            SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createSQLQuery(sql);
            if (user.getId() != null) {
                sqlQuery.setLong("id", user.getId());
                if (userBefore.getPassword() != user.getPassword()) {
                    sqlQuery.setString("password", user.getPassword());
                }
            } else {
                sqlQuery.setString("password", user.getPassword());
            }
            sqlQuery.setString("firstName", user.getFirstName());
            sqlQuery.setString("lastName", user.getLastName());
            sqlQuery.setString("email", user.getEmail());
            sqlQuery.setDate("created", user.getCreated());
            sqlQuery.setDate("lastUpdated", user.getLastUpdated());
            sqlQuery.setDate("emailConfirmedAt", user.getEmailConfirmedAt());

            sqlQuery.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DaoException("Error at saving "
                    + user.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Console log shows this:

Hibernate: select user0_.id as id8_, user0_.created as created8_, user0_.last_updated as last3_8_, user0_.email as email8_, user0_.email_confirmed_at as email5_8_, user0_.first_name as first6_8_, user0_.last_name as last7_8_, user0_.password as password8_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=?

**Hibernate: update users set created=?, last_updated=?, email=?, email_confirmed_at=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, password=? where id=?**

Hibernate: select user0_.id as id8_, user0_.created as created8_, user0_.last_updated as last3_8_, user0_.email as email8_, user0_.email_confirmed_at as email5_8_, user0_.first_name as first6_8_, user0_.last_name as last7_8_, user0_.password as password8_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=?

Hibernate: update users set first_name=?, last_name=?, email=?, created=?, last_updated=?, email_confirmed_at=? where id=?
why ?

**Hibernate: update users set created=?, last_updated=?, email=?, email_confirmed_at=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, password=? where id=?**

I'm not understanding why is executing this two updates that are not coded anywhere. The problem is that I'm using MD5 on postgres to encrypt the user's password, and I cannot let it update the password every time some other attribute gets updated, or else the password will be encrypted again, changing it, but right now those two updates not coded are setting the password in database without encrypting it to "novo password".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're doing hibernate's work for it by writing the insert/update queries. Hibernate can already do that stuff for you.

Comment: What do you suggest doing to just update the password field when it is really changed to avoid redo the md5 encryption?

Comment: I suggest you have the actual md5 password field and a separate setter on your java class which allows the plaintext password to be set - this would be run through the MD5 before it's stored in the md5 field. I suggest you decorate the user class with JPA fields and use hibernate to select and update the user object without dropping to writing queries - the entity itself can be loaded, saved and deleted from native methods. Why are you trying to impose your own SQL on this?

Comment: I want to use postgres MD5 encryption, and not deal with it on java. I found a way to avoid my problem, thanks for your suggestions Ashley.

Comment: End up using @Transient annotation and doing native sql when I need to change the value of the password column.